# Linear functions with parameter in maple

Tags: maple

Please help me, Im new in Maple. Dont you know how I can solve this?

> Matrix(3, 3, {(1, 1) = 863138, (1, 2) = -332862, (1, 3) = -530302, (2, 1) = 1726276, (2, 2) = -665724, (2, 3) = -530302*m, (3, 1) = -863138, (3, 2) = -998586, (3, 3) = -1060604})
>
> Vector(3, {(1) = 8, (2) = -8, (3) = -4*m})

Matrix = Vector and solve it depending on the parametr in Maple...please whole solutions, I have not already had linear algebra. Thank you.

Comment: Please anyone for help...

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you are asking how to solve the system of linear equations `M . XYZ = V` where `M` is your given Matrix, `V` is your given Vector, and `XYZ` is a Vector with entries as three variables. You can use Maple's `LinearAlgebra` package as solve that system (without even needing to specify `XYZ`, or you can form the three explicit equations and use Maple's `solve` command on those.

```
M := Matrix([ [ 863138,  -332862, -530302   ],
              [ 1726276, -665724, -530302*m ],
              [ -863138, -998586, -1060604  ]]):

V := Vector([ 8, -8, -4*m ]):
```

First way,

```
with(LinearAlgebra):

sol1 := LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve(M,V);

                              [  2           ]
                              [ m  + 4 m - 6 ]
                              [--------------]
                              [863138 (m - 2)]
                              [              ]
                              [ 2            ]
                              [m  - 4 m - 14 ]
                              [--------------]
                              [332862 (m - 2)]
                              [              ]
                              [      12      ]
                              [--------------]
                              [265151 (m - 2)]
```

And the linear system and solution `sol1` can be put in terms of three variables,

```
XYZ := Vector([ x, y, z ]):

M . XYZ = V;

            [  863138 x - 332862 y - 530302 z  ]   [ 8  ]
            [                                  ]   [    ]
            [-530302 m z + 1726276 x - 665724 y] = [ -8 ]
            [                                  ]   [    ]
            [ -863138 x - 998586 y - 1060604 z ]   [-4 m]

Equate(XYZ, sol1);

    [      2                  2                                ]
    [     m  + 4 m - 6       m  - 4 m - 14             12      ]
    [x = --------------, y = --------------, z = --------------]
    [    863138 (m - 2)      332862 (m - 2)      265151 (m - 2)]
```

Now, another way, using three explicit equations,

```
reduc := LUDecomposition(Matrix([M,V]),output=U);

              [863138  -332862         -530302           8    ]
              [                                               ]
              [  0     -1331448       -1590906        -4 m + 8]
              [                                               ]
              [  0        0      -530302 m + 1060604    -24   ]

GenerateEquations(reduc, convert(XYZ,list));

      [863138 x - 332862 y - 530302 z = 8,-1331448 y - 1590906 z = -4 m + 8,
       -530302 (m - 2) z = -24]

sol2 := solve(%,[x,y,z]);

       [[      2                  2                                ]]
       [[     m  + 4 m - 6       m  - 4 m - 14             12      ]]
       [[x = --------------, y = --------------, z = --------------]]
       [[    863138 (m - 2)      332862 (m - 2)      265151 (m - 2)]]
```

Notice that `sol1` and `sol2` agree. Note also that substituting `m=2` into the result `reduc` above would produce an inconsistent system where the 3rd row down represented the impossible `0*x + 0*y + 0*z = -24`.